# Using two different SELECT elements depending on input value, but only second one in page posts correctly

Tags: javascript, html, post, hidden-field

I have an inventory form which I have been asked to improve.  The user counts product and enters the new count into the form.  Then, depending on whether the input is positive or negative, a select box appears with the list of reasons for the discrepancy.  The UI is working perfectly, but the reason code will only pass for whichever select element is listed last.

Basically this works to ensure the user is entering negatives correctly so my default is to have the SELECT element for the negative reason second since it will be the one to work.  I would appreciate any suggestions for a better approach.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#invAmt").val()=='') {
        $("#plus").hide();
        $("#minus").hide();
    } 
    //return false;
  
  $(document).on('change', '#invAmt', function() {
     if ($("#invAmt").val()>='1') {
        $("#plus").show();
        $("#minus").hide();
    } else {
        $("#plus").hide();
        $("#minus").show();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="invDec">Enter Amount of Units to Adjust (+/-): </label>
                <input name="invAmt" id="invAmt" style="width:50px" >
        </div>
        <label for="title">Reason for Adjustment:</label>
        
        
        <div class="plus">
            <select class="custom-select custom-select-md" name="reason" id="plus" style="width:370px">
            <option value="">--- Select Reason ---</option>
            <option value="30">Returned Product</option>
            <option value="50">Other (explain in notes)</option></select>
        </div>      
        
        <div class="minus">
            <select  class="custom-select custom-select-md" name="reason" id="minus" style="width:370px">
            <option value="">--- Select Reason ---</option>
            <option value="70">Recount (lost)</option>
            <option value="75">Dumped / Died)</option>
            <option value="90">Diseased / Pest</option>
            <option value="65">Overgrown</option>
            <option value="95">Overstock</option>
            <option value="98">Loaned Out</option>
            <option value="100">Other (explain in notes)</option></select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select multiple options from your drop downs you need to add the "multiple" attribute to your two select statements.  Like this:

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-md" multiple name="reason" id="plus" style="width:370px">
```

also, you need to add a submit button.

If you are trying to get just one option for + and one option for - you need to use different names for each of your select boxes.  If they are both name='reason' the last one will overwrite the first one.  Try:

```
name='negReason'
name='posReason'
```

Comment: The intent was to use only one of the two select elements, depending on the value of the input (invAmt).  The code works correctly as far at the UI.  If a positive number is entered in invAmt the #plus select code appears, if negative the #minus.  My issue is that the reason code is posted only for the negative (#minus) select element, but not the positive (the field is empty).  If I invert the order of the select elements, the positive reason code will be posted and the minus will be empty.

Comment: give them different names

Comment: My challenge is that it uses the name for the $_POST, so if I have different names I will need to post both and then do a compare to figure out which is valid.  I am investigating using JS to replace the <option></option> values depending on the input value.